# Best way to separate Sequel model definitions into different file?

Tags: ruby, sequel

I'm using the Sequel gem in Ruby, but at the moment I have my model definitions up at the top of each of my scripts. However, as those models have changed over time, it's becoming hard to keep track of what the latest model is when I open up, say, an older file.

I'd like to keep my model definitions in it's own .rb file, but is that possible? If so, what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it's possible. Extract the definitions into their own file (say, `models.rb`), and put `require_relative('models')` where they used to be.

Or you can even put each model in its own file in a directory, say `models/person.rb`..., and then

```
Dir["models/*.rb"].each { |file| require_relative(file) }
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly.

Comment: ActiveSupport's auto-loader can also handle this, or you can make your own version of same. Splitting them out into separate files is really the best way to do this, though.

Comment: @tadman: For sure, but neither [tag:rails] nor [tag:activesupport] were tagged.

Comment: Oh, not forcing Rails on anyone, but if ActiveSupport is being used, which sometimes is the case, it does have a fancy auto-loader.